# Why Client statistics display wrong rows return by select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am running simple sql statement

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON
SELECT * FROM dbo.tblAmount
```

Statement return 11 rows as in image.

[image]

but while looking at client statistics of same query I am getting Rows returned by SELECT statements is 12, Why? Please look at image.

[image]

Comment: These statistics include three select statements. If you run SQL profiler you can see what the other two are. They are probably to do with returning the statistics.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the extra row comes from the headers: `AmtID` and `Amount`